# Queue don't start in Laravel

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-artisan, listen

I try:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

But the result is a empty:
[picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thR57.png)

What should happen?

I want it to execute the code:

```
$job = (new SendEmail())->delay(10);
$this->dispatch($job);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what should happen. It means it's waiting for something to be pushed to the queue.

If you carry out an action that pushes something to the queue, through an event or job etc. then you will see something like

```
-bash-4.1$ php artisan queue:listen
[2016-07-22 09:27:57] Processed: App\Listeners\Users\SendWelcomeEmail@handle
```

Have you definitely set up the correct queue driver (e.g. `database`) in your .env or `config/queue.php` file?

Comment: yes, .env: `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`.
migration completed.
`dd(env('QUEUE_DRIVER'));` => "database".

but delay don't work... performed synchronously.

I don't see in command line it, only empty: `-bash-4.1$ php artisan queue:listen
[2016-07-22 09:27:57] Processed: App\Listeners\Users\SendWelcomeEmail@handle`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had to create job with --queue

`php artisan make:job SendEmail --queued` Thanks!

Comment: Ah right, no problem. Glad you got it working. It probably was down to the missing `implements ShouldQueue` from the class definition, which stopped it being pushed onto the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the storage/logs/laravel.log file.
You might find an error message saying `could not find driver` indicating a problem with your database driver.( if you have specified `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` )

If you're using XAMPP, please enable the PDO driver for the database in the php.ini file. Alternatively, you can install the necessary extensions.

Also, ensure that the path specified in the environment variable points to the correct PHP folder.